# Syncing AppleID and local user password

Tags: apple-id, password, data-synchronization, user-account

We're Apple Business Manager and Azure users.  I'm looking for a way of using AppleScript or Automator to perform synchronization of my AppleID password and local user password at boot time or on a schedule.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?